# css3 multi-columns any number of columns based on width

Tags: css

Is it possible to setup columns 100px wide, however many will fit in the div, in css3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `column-width` to 100px and optionally specify a `column-gap`, like this:

```
p {
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    -moz-column-width: 100px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

The `column-width` is just the optimal width, but may be adjusted to fit in the div.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/9RRdp/

Comment: Thanks, I've only ever seen the column-count version of things.